# Implement Geolocation API of Phonegap Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Has anybody implemented geolocation using the geolocation API of Phonegap in Android. I was reading the documentation but didn't have much progress on that...

Answer (score 0):

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { frequency: 3000 });
```

onScuccess and onError are the method names which will call after execution of the related          plugin (this plugin java file will be in the phonegap.jar)......... you can rename this onSuccess, onError methods as you want..... but u have to take care that u have to rename the function name also... and last parameter is json object with with options

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I use geolocation in one of my apps. You start with something like:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  geolocSuccess,
  error,
  {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 1000000, maximumAge: 2000000}
);
```

`geolocSuccess` can be something like (watered-down version):

```
function geolocSuccess(position) {
  var lat=position.coords.latitude;
  var longit=position.coords.longitude;
  var time=position.timestamp;
  var whereAmI = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, longit);
}
```

HTH